# How to Get Category Name When Export Products

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, export

I'm writing an export plugin for WooCommerce. I want to print the product categories and subcategories in separate columns while exporting the products in the plugin I developed.

My code is as below.

```
function wpae_wp_all_export_csv_headers( $headers, $export_id ) {
global $wpdb;
$last_id = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT id FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'bek_export' . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ');
    if ( $export_id == $last_id++ ) { 
        $additional_headers = array(
            'Category 1',
            'Category 2',
            'Category 3',
            'Category 4',
            'Sub-Category 1',
            'Sub-Category 2',
            'Sub-Category 3',
            'Sub-Category 4'
        );
        $headers = array_merge( $headers, $additional_headers );
    }
    return $headers; 
}

function wp_all_export_csv_rows( $articles, $options, $export_id ) {
global $wpdb;
$last_id = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT id FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'bek_export' . ' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ');    
    if ( $export_id == $last_id++ ) { // change to your export ID
        foreach( $articles as $key => $article ) {
            if ( array_key_exists( 'ID', $article ) ) {
                $i = 1;
                $product = wc_get_product( $article['ID'] );

                if ( ! empty( $product ) ) {

                    $m_category = get_term_by( 'id',  'product_cat' );

                    if ( ! empty( $m_category ) ) {
                        foreach ( $m_category as $id ) {
                            $articles[ $key ]['Category '] = $m_category;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    return $articles; // Return the array of records to export
```

But the code returning nothing to csv column.

**Update 1**

I changed code. I am getting categories names with url below

```
 <a href=http://url.net/product-category/harnesses/ rel=tag>Harnesses</a>
```

Code below

```
$m_category = wc_get_product_category_list( $product-> get_id() );
    if ( ! empty( $m_category ) ) {
    // use $m_category->parent to check if it's a parent category or sub-category.
    $articles[ $key ]['Category ' . $i] = $m_category->name; //category name from category object
                            }
```

Comment: Discussions on third-party plugins are off-topic here. You will get better and precise help in WooCommerce support channels.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this block of code

```php
if ( ! empty( $m_category ) ) {
   foreach ( $m_category as $id ) {
       $articles[ $key ]['Category '] = $m_category;
   }
}
```

to be something like this:

```php
if ( ! empty( $m_category ) ) {
   // use $m_category->parent to check if it's a parent category or sub-category.
   $articles[ $key ]['Category '] = $m_category->name; //category name from category object
}
```

Comment: I am trying right now. Thank you.

Comment: Wordpress says "Undefined variable: m_category and is_search was called incorrectly." I don't understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please check the website error logs, this may help you find the detailed information about the problem